# Apply css to body but only in words of a certain length

Tags: css

I need to apply css to the body of my page. A want to capitalize all words but only in words of X length.

```
body { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

I realy don't know if this is possible to do or not.

Thank you.

Comment: you would have to use js to decide if the words are a certain length - CSS cannot do this alone

Comment: That’s what I thought. But I was hoping that where a way using only CSS

Comment: You're better off finding any longer words with javascript and adding a span.classname to them and targeting them.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira: CSS is for styling, not for manipulation. Hence why this requires manipulation to decide if the textual content is over a certain length (hence not possible with CSS alone). There isn't such a selector as `word-of-length`, and quite frankly, I'm not sure there ever will be.